# WLAN roaming on same, or different channel

Tags: wireless-networking

I've setup a router in my basement, and an access point in my attic floor. They are connected with a patch cable. Both have the same SSID and WPA2 security. Roaming does work. But, what I want to know is, if I need to set them on different channels, or do they need the exact same channel to share. I've read many community forums and manuals, but yet it is not clear what to do because they have different opinions.

- Router: Fritz!Box 7270
- Accesspoint: Netgear WN604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use WDS you need to use the same channel. If you use cable network between them, use different channels - roaming is based on SSID, not channel and if you've got less interference using different channels.

Answer (score 1):

Your access points are using WDS to bridge the network. It requires you have to have same channel, ssid and encryption settings on both APs.

Comment: You don't have to use the same [SSID](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/how-to-wds-bridge,review-253-4.html).